# Instance scope of micro Service in API gateway

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I want to change scope of service instance scope from Singleton to  Transient(where it create instance every request) using service url but getting compile time error

Below is working code without service url

```
services.AddTransient(typeof(IUser), typeof(My.UserService));
```

Below is singleton scope with service url

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IUser), ServiceProxy.Create<IUser>(new Uri("fabric:/My.Microservices/MY.UserService")));
```

Now I want to add scope as Transient using service url like singleton, how?

Comment: And what is the compile time error?

Answer (score 0):

Use the generic approach for registering your service, along with a factory delegate

```
services.AddTransient<IUser>(sp => 
    ServiceProxy.Create<IUser>(new Uri("fabric:/My.Microservices/MY.UserService"))
);
```

In the above code, every time `IUser` is resolved the delegate will be invoked.